# Using SAS to group column values into discrete variables

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sas, statistics

I basically have a table like this:

```
   X1    X2   X3   Y1   Y2    Y3
A
B
C
D
E
```

All of these columns have codes like "C71" or "D38" and I want to be able to convert all the "C71" = 1 and all the "D38", "H80", "C91" = 2 etc so that instead of looking at many different codes, I can group the codes that have similar meanings into a single number or variable across all the columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead.

```
data want;
  set have;

  array orig(*) x1-x3 y1-y3;
  array recoded(*) z1-z6;

  do i=1 to dim(orig);
    if orig(i) in ('C71', 'D38') then recoded(i)=1;
    else if orig(i) in ('D38', 'H80', 'C91') then recoded(i) = 2;
  end;

 run;
```

Another option is to use a format but that really depends on what you're trying to do in your next step.